# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'try.tb_stores.division' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day I was trying to run this query but I encountered an error even though the column do exist in tb_divisions.

Can somebody help me how to solve this error:

> Unknown column 'try.tb_stores.division' in 'on clause?

-- 2. Store Migration

```
INSERT INTO `try`.`tb_stores`
(
`try`.`tb_stores`.`subscription`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`client`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`division`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`code`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`name`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`location`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`user`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`created_at`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`updated_at`
)
SELECT
1,                                                                          -- subscription
`try`.`tb_clients`.`id` AS `client`,                                        -- client
`try`.`tb_divisions`.`id` AS `division`,                                    -- division
`dba_department`.`code`,                                                    -- code
`dba_department`.`descrip`,                                                 -- name
CONCAT('Region ',`dba_department`.`region_num`) AS region,                  -- location
2,                                                                          -- user
NOW(),                                                                      -- created_at
NOW()                                                                       -- updated_at
FROM `test`.`dba_department`
LEFT JOIN `try`.`tb_clients`
ON `test`.`dba_department`.`company` = `try`.`tb_clients`.`companycode`;
```

[image]

I used LEFT JOIN but still error.
-- 2. Store Migration

```
INSERT INTO `try`.`tb_stores`
(
`try`.`tb_stores`.`subscription`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`client`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`division`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`code`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`name`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`location`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`user`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`created_at`,
`try`.`tb_stores`.`updated_at`
)
SELECT
1,                                                                          -- subscription
`try`.`tb_clients`.`id` AS `client`,                                        -- client
`try`.`tb_divisions`.`id` AS `division`,                                    -- division
`dba_department`.`code`,                                                    -- code
`dba_department`.`descrip`,                                                 -- name
CONCAT('Region ',`dba_department`.`region_num`) AS region,                  -- location
2,                                                                          -- user
NOW(),                                                                      -- created_at
NOW()                                                                       -- updated_at
FROM `test`.`dba_department`
LEFT JOIN `try`.`tb_clients`
ON `test`.`dba_department`.`company` = `try`.`tb_clients`.`companycode`
LEFT JOIN `try`.`tb_divisions`
ON `try`.`tb_stores`.`division` = `try`.`tb_divisions`.`id`;
```

Comment: Either the `company` column does not exist, the `companycode` column does not exist, or neither exist.

Comment: Your query doesn't use `tb_divisions` in any part of the `JOIN` operation. Can you post the exact error message that you get?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry I forgot to type in the error. the error was Unknown column 'try.tb_stores.division' in 'on clause'.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos The error is still the same even though I use join in tb_divisions.

Comment: In that case can you post the *actual* query that generates this error?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I edited my current question sir with the LEFT JOIN query.

Comment: Can you try getting rid of the aliases in the `SELECT`?  You don't need them, and maybe they are causing problems.

Comment: Division is a function name in MySQL. Have you tried to remove these division alias or rename the column? I know that the commas will resolve this, but I think that could be the issue

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sir I removed the aliases but still got the error.

Comment: Maybe your division column not yet saved.. or a new column. Could you try to change column name?

Comment: @kiks73 Sir I already tried to remove the aliases and run the query but still the same error.

Comment: @kiks73 I followed your suggestion and rename the `division` column to `division_id` the same error message Unknown column 'try.tb_stores.division_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Table `tb_stores` is not used in the `FROM` clause. How to you expect to access a field of this table in the `ON` clause?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos what should I do sir? I mean what should be the missing recipe to fix this error? so that I can insert the tb_division id to tb_strores division.

Comment: I suspect mysql is objecting because  left join to tb.divisions is tryng to join on a field you are trying to insert (a circular reference). Is there a relationship between either of the 2 other tables and divisions (directly or indirectly) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are just using table department and client but not **tb_stores** that's why you got this error:

[image]